# Can I clone a repository to 2 distinct directories?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

When I fix a bug, I then have to run all the unit tests. That takes about 15 minutes. If I have a clone of the same branch in a different directory, I can switch over to that directory and work on the next bug while the unit tests run.

I do pretty much all my operations on the repository with VisualStudio 2017. And the code is on Git under VSO (now Azure DevOps).

Is there any problem with doing this? Including having VisualStudio open on the C# projects in both local cloned copies of the repository?

Comment: Leveraging Azure DevOps hosted agents to run test suites and validate the build is a relatively easy thing to implement, either by having a CI trigger on a lifetime branch that you've merged into and pushed on, or pushing your dev branch and setting the builds target branch for a manually queued build. Both remove your need to manage a separate clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to do this - it's common to have multiple clones in different locations - for example on different computers - the only issue is making sure that if you develop in 2 locations at once, you don't get too lost in merging and rebasing.

However, a better approach would be to have your unit tests run against a particular commit. That way your workflow is to push to a 'testing' branch when you want to test, and having the unit test system clone/check out that branch into a temporary folder and test that code.

This has a couple of advantages - it lets you keep working while tests are running, but it also means that the tests can be associated with a particular commit, meaning that you don't accidentally run the tests against your local repo, only to then modify it, but believe the code has tested successfully.

IF you scale things up, you can even have a continuous integration system monitoring the 'testing' branch(es) and triggering a test run on every commit to that branch.

Comment: But this is 2 locations on the SAME computer - is that fine too? (As to the testing branch, I just go with the system we have in place.)

Comment: Yes - you can clone as much as you like wherever you like - it's only if you try to clone a repo *inside* another repo that things can get tricky.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical reason that git or the IDE should have a problem with this.

It is a somewhat fragile workflow, and I would consider doing something different.  Just as one example, if you're working on the next bug but the unit tests fail, how do you handle that situation?

Comment: For each bug I branch from master. Once the tests all pas I push up to that branch and create a pull request. So at the end of the day say I have 17 bugs fixed, then 17 branches and 17 pull requests, each distinct.